A commutative ring with unity which does not have relatively pseudo-injective ideals with zero intersection
Let $R$ be a ring with $1$ and $M$ and $N$ be any right $R$-modules. We say that $M$ is pseudo-$N$-injective if every $R$-monomorphism $f:X \to M$ from a submodule $X_R$ of $N_R$ can be extended to $N$. The modules $M$ and $N$ are called relatively pseudo-injective if $M$ is pseudo-$N$-injective and $N$ is pseudo-$M$-injective.
Can we find a commutative ring $R$ with unity such that there exist two ideals $A,B \subseteq R$ such that $A \cap B=0$ and $A_R$ is NOT pseudo-$B_R$-injective.

Can we find a commutative ring $$ with unity such that there exist two ideals $A, B\subseteq R$ such that $A\cap B=0$ and $_$ is NOT pseudo-$_$-injective?
Let $R=\mathbb Z[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$, let $A=(x)\lhd R$, and let $B=(y)\lhd R$. $A$ is the additive subgroup generated by $x$ and $B$ is the additive subgroup generated by $y$, so $A\cap B=\{0\}$. Let $X = (2y)\subseteq B$ be the infinite cyclic subgroup generated by $2y$. The $R$-isomorphism $f\colon X\to A\colon 2y\mapsto x$  cannot be extended to $B$, since if it could then (since $y+y=2y$) the element $f(y)$ would  have to be an element $a\in A \;(= (x) = \mathbb Z\cdot x)$ such that $a+a=f(2y)=x$. But there is no $a\in A$
such that $a+a=x$.
